# vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "query is a required parameter and is not present in the options!"

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

[image: Error console screenshot]

My router.js:

```
{ name: 'article', path: '/article/:id', component: Article}
```

My Aricle.vue:

```
export default {
    name: 'home',
    components: {
    },
    data() {
        return {
            type: 'tv',
            data:'',
            poster:''
        }
    },
    mounted() {
    },
    created() {
        if(this.$route.params.id = "1") {
            // Something
        }
    },
}
```

I am trying to use a parameter in created()
but something going wrong
I cant process the parameter
How can I fix that?

Comment: You need to access the param like `this.$route.params.id`.

Comment: thanks but i have same error

Comment: The code you have provided should work so the issue must lie elsewhere. What other libraries are you using?